# Find a possible line that is tangent to both $\cos(xy) = 1+ \sin(y)$ and $y = x^2$

Tags: derivatives

**Question:** Find a line that is tangent to both $\cos(xy) = 1+ \sin(y)$ and $y = x^2$

My first attempt is to differentiate both to get:

$$ (1) \ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y \sin(xy)}{\cos(y) + x \sin(xy)} \ (2) y' =2x$$

We need to find values where the tangent lines are the same so I set (1) to equal (2) and get:

$$2x = \frac{-y \sin(xy)}{\cos(y) + x \sin(xy)}$$

My first idea is to pick some value for $y$ so that I am able to solve for it, so I set $y = 0$. This produces the result  $2x= 0$ and hence making the line of tangent $y = 0$.

However, I am wondering if there is a better way of getting a general solution without speculating on a good value for $y$. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to draw a picture of the two graphs?

Comment: Yes I did. its a messy function

Comment: "We need to find values where the tangent lines are the same so I set (1) to equal (2)"  ---  If you want the general solution, note that the problem as you've written it is even a bit more general than that.  A line may be tangent to both curves without being tangent to them _at the same point_, which is what you're assuming here.

Comment: I suspect that $y=0$ is the expected answer. There are infinitely more, but they are not easily found.